# Changing elements of a list

Tags: netlogo

I wish to update/change elements of list with 2 elements as follows:

```
set (item 0 vK)  (item 0 vK-1) + ((item 0 rpos) + beta-exit * (item 0 gpos)  + (item 0 wpos) * time-step) 
set (item 1 vK)  (item 1 vK-1) + ((item 1 rpos) + beta-exit * (item 1 gpos)  + (item 1 wpos) * time-step)
```

**But it gives me the error:**

> This isn't something you can use set on.

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So [`replace-item`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#replace-item) is the general way to replace an item in a list.

However, looking at your code, I think [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) would better serve you:

```
set vK (map [?1 + (?2 + beta-exit * ?3 + ?4 * time-step)] vK-1 rpos gpos wpos)
```

`map` iterates through the given lists, applying the given task to the elements of the lists, and creates a new list from the results.

Comment: I understand your answer. I was looking more for the reason of the above error.

Comment: There are languages where syntax like this is supported (for example, Common Lisp's generalized `setf` construct). NetLogo just isn't one of them. There isn't any special reason this particular feature isn't supported; it's just that we like to keep the language small, for a lot of reasons.